# How to resolve issue module 'cx_Oracle' has no attribute 'connect'?

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, cx-oracle, aws-lambda-layers

I'm trying to connect Oracle RDS by using **Cx_Oracle**. For that I'm using **Python3.9** and **Cx_Oracle8.3.0**. But I am getting issue **module 'cx_Oracle' has no attribute 'connect'**

Can anyone help me to fix this issue.

My code:

```
import os
import json
import cx_Oracle
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    message = ""
    cursor = None
    connection = None

    try:
        connection = cx_Oracle.connect("myuser", "pwd", "host:port/orcl")
        
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("select * from mytable")
        data=cursor.fetchAll()
        for row in data:
            logging.info(row)
            
    except Exception as e:
        message = str(e)
        
    finally:
        if cursor:
            cursor.close()
        if connection:
            connection.close()
            
    return {'message' : message}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Check what is stored in the variable `cx_Oracle`. Often this is not what you expect!